# Format java code in HTML to display it like in an IDE

Tags: java, html, css, formatting, ide

I am searching for a way to display my Java code on a HTML page as if it were in an IDE. Is there something already existing that can be used? I couldn't find anything so far. Typically, I'd like something more or less like that:

[image]

Instead of something like that:

[image]

Comment: Use https://highlightjs.org/

Comment: @minus What if I also want to be able to modify the displayed code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some editors written in Javascript like ACE :

https://ace.c9.io/

You can use it for view and for editing code directly from your browser...

Comment: This tool is really powerful, it's perfect for what I need to do (i.e. see formatetd code and edit it).

Comment: Is there a way to check the syntax as well?